# jQuery SerializeArray and Not selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, serializearray

I am using the .serializeArray function to gather all of the inputs of a form but I want to exclude inputs within a certain div class.  I thought the .not() selector would do this but it does not appear to be working.

At its most basic level here is my code:

HTML:

```
<form class="theForm">
  <input name="a" value="a"/>
  <div class="excludeMe">
    <input name="c" value="c"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$.each($(".theForm").not(".excludeMe").serializeArray(), 
function() {
    alert(this.name);
});
```

I would expect the alert to just be 'a' but this is alerting 'a' and then 'b'.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cysaczu5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap all inputs in `<div><input/></div>`

And then change the selector to this `$.each($(".theForm :not(.excludeMe) input")`

https://jsfiddle.net/cysaczu5/3/

I would recommend to remove the div and add the "excludeMe" class to the inputs directly. Then the selector becomes `$.each($(".theForm input:not(.excludeMe)")`

Comment: This worked - thanks.  I tried the :not() solution but I was not placed a space after .theForm

Answer (score 0):

Well use this class on the inputs not divs and it will work.

```
'


 $.each($("input").not(".excludeMe").serializeArray(), 
   function() {
    alert(this.name);
});
```

'

```
<input name="c" class='excludeMe' value="c"/>
```

[JSFidle](https://jsfiddle.net/cysaczu5/4/)

Comment: I have tried that by moving the "excludeMe" class onto the Input and it did not work either.

Comment: Look at the example in JSFiddle it works fine :) Also you should loop all inputs not class selector.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
<form class="theForm">
<input name="a" value="a"/>
<div class="excludeMe">
  <input class="excludeMe" name="c" value="c"/>
</div>
</form>
$.each($(".theForm :not(.excludeMe)").serializeArray(), 
function() {
    alert(this.name);
});
```

Comment: There is no difference between your code and the OP's one.. you should add `input` before `:not` in order to make it work as it should

Comment: You need to add the input after the :not as @lipp suggested

Comment: @MateiMihai - There is a difference I have added `class="excludeMe"` to input. As `"not(.excludeMe)"` will exclude form items having class `"excludeMe"` I have added it to input. Also  `"input after the :not"` is not compulsory. View [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ouc79nm/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The most simple answer would be to remove the `name` attribute from the inputs you want to skip. This way it is also skipped by `serializeArray()`:

HTML:

```
<form class="theForm">
  <input name="a" value="a" />
  <input value="c" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$.each($(".theForm").serializeArray(), function() {
    alert(this.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put `input` before `:not` statement to match only the inputs inside the form, not the form itself:

```
$.each($(".theForm input:not(.excludeMe)").serializeArray(), function() {
    alert(this.name);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cysaczu5/5/